# Running methods from another class in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

I've been trying out Java with Eclipse and I'm having trouble running methods from another class. I have read other posts about this subject, but I still couldn't get it to work.

Here is my code: (All files are in the same Java project)

(Code from one file called Hello.java)

```
public class Hello {
    public void printText(){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

(Code from another file called TestHello.java)

```
public class TestHello{
    public void main(){
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        hello.printText();
    }
}
```

So, in Eclipse, I save all the files, and then press CTRL + F11 to run the file called TestHello.java, and it is supposed to use the method from Hello.java and print Hello World but it doesn't print anything. It gives me an empty console.

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: main method is `public static void main(String[] args)` for TestHello

Comment: `public static void main`

Comment: BTW, Eclipse has a code completion capability, and you can use it to insert the "main" method, which would then avoid these types of issues.

Comment: @KevinO ...and you would never learn.

Answer (score 7):

In order to run a java file, you need a `main` method, but it has to look exactly like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   //code here
}
```

your `public void main()` is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This here is wrong because the start point of the app is `static void main(String[] ars)`

```
public void main(){
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        hello.printText();
    }
```

it must be

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        hello.printText();
    }
```